# I am using twilio functions(inbuilt feature supporting node js) for IVR and logging details in zoho crm and want to log what key caller pressed

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio functions(in built feature supporting  node js) for IVR and logging details in zoho crm .So I want to know in zoho crm that what key is pressed by the caller for given options in twilio IVR

1st function

```
exports.handler=function(context, event, callback){
  const twiml=new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.gather({
    numDigits:1,
    timeout:5,
    hints:1,
    action:'/Book-Ride'
  }).say('Welcome to Softnet Relocations Transportation services.Press 1 for Transportation services information,Press 2 for ShareRoute services');
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

2nd Function(Book-Ride)

```
exports.handler=function(context,event,callback){
  const twiml=new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  switch(event.Digits){
    case'1':
        twiml.say('getting info');
        twiml.redirect('transportation-info');
        break;
    case'2':
        twiml.redirect('ShareRoute-services');
        break;
    default:twiml.say('Invalid input');
      twiml.Reject();
      break;
  }
  callback(null,twiml);
};
```

If pressed 1 in 1st function then redirects to 'transportation-info' function and for 2  'ShareRoute-services' function

And I want to trace this event user pressed key and log in zoho crm.
Can is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Functions run Node.js and it appears that [Zoho CRM has an API](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/overview.html) and a [Node module](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/server-side-sdks/node-js.html). I've not worked with it myself, but I would imagine that you could make calls to the Zoho API in your second function in order to log the responses from your user.